# How do I align text inside a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school project and I need to align the text inside my footer to the right side of the page.

I've tried using text-align, turning the whole thing into a flexbox and then aligning but it just won't work. This is my css:

```
footer {
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
bottom: 2%;
text-align: right;
}
```

anybody got some ideas about what's going on? Thanks in advance

EDIT: Someone asked for html, so here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mystyle.css">
  <title>MyPage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe></iframe>
  <footer>MyName 2019</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a `width:100%;` and see what change it makes. Or add an appropriate as per your grid settings.

Comment: Show us your `html` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 2%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    /* text-align: right; */
}
```

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuf4qg

Comment: Why using angular for such a simple example? 

Comment: i work  on angular projects regularly !!so I just went for stackblitz and just made this thing!! as a habit made it in angular

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```css
.fixed {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.elements {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="elements">
    <p>Centered Elements</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is the live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Devel0per95/67rjmvw3/9/